# Check if click event was started inside an element

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose we have stuff like this:

```js
document.querySelector("#foo").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
#foo {
  width: max-content;
  background: #aeaeae;
  padding: 5em;
}

#bar {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">Text Here</div>
</div>
```

Now if one tries to select text inside `#bar` and takes mouse outside it while keeping the mouse button down, the target logged is `#foo`. Is there some way we can run code inside click handler only if someone has clicked in that gray area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for `mousedown` instead of `click`.

```js
document.querySelector("#foo").addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
#foo {
  width: max-content;
  background: #aeaeae;
  padding: 5em;
}

#bar {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">Text Here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `mouseDown` will eliminate the possibility of drag/ select. But not sure if OP is looking for this.

Comment: Ah, thanks. This should work with some checks like e.button is 0 and closest is not bar.